# Session set but not allow to access Admin page

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, vue.js, axios

I'm really new to `CodeIgniter`. I have a problem with my code, I created a login system with Axios through `Vue`. The session was successfully set but I am still not allowed to access the admin page, I use `Ajax` to send data from the view and the data is successfully received on the controller.

The login process has been successfully running and I have created a session for that, when I throw a fallback return to `Vue`, the session is successfully read but when I switch pages to the admin page the session is unreadable and the page is redirected to the login page, what's wrong with my code?

```
$uname = $this->input->post('username');
$upass = $this->input->post('password');
$utype = $this->input->post('types');
$where = array('user'=>$uname, 'pass'=>md5($upass), 'type'=>$utype);
$check = $this->Login_models->login_check("user", $where)->num_rows(); //account checking
$type = $this->Login_models->check_user_identity($utype)->row_array(); //user check, admin or student
    if ($check > 0) {
        $this->_result['error'] = FALSE;
            if($type['type'] == 'admin'){
                $data_session = array('nama'=>$uname, 'status'=>"admin");
                $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
                $this->_result['type'] = 'admin';
            }
            else if($type['type'] == 'student'){
                $data_session1 = array('nama'=>$uname, 'status'=>"student");
                $this->session->set_userdata($data_session1);
                $this->_result['type'] = 'student';
            }
    }else{
        $this->_result['error'] = TRUE;
        $this->_result['message'] = array(
            'no_account' => 'Account not found'
        );
    }
}
echo json_encode($this->_result);
```

Comment: `please help me, I'am on deadline`, it sounds like you're in dire need of an expert. Feel free to contract one! Don't miss that deadline! In the mean time, why don't you have a [read over JWT integration for Auth with CodeIgniter](https://github.com/dodistyo/ci-rest-jwt).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Also please don't circumvent the tools that are in place to guide people to ask better questions, like replacing the `.` with a `*` in the pastebin url. The system is set up to guide people to supply the code that is relevant to their question and pastebin bypasses that.

Comment: Are you sending the bearer token in header?